# create _layouts father and children

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

good morning everyone,

In my learning process and I have been looking for how to include static html as it is done in php with `include ()` in a layout.net core design view to make my modular layout and thus have separate elements like asides menus nav foooter etc. and not having to repeat code in each of the layouts.

Someone suggested that parents and children can do layouts but the documentation is scarce or almost null and more if you look for it in Spanish.

Could someone help me with a tutorial or the code with which I can make such a cshtml inclusion?

And thank you very much in advance

Comment: The docs cover this. Specifically, look at layouts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and sections (same page) and partial views (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: thanks, your answer helped me a lot Chris Pratt